# Why the ModalBottomSheet is behind the navigation bar?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

I need to implement a `ModalBottomSheet` in my app. But before doing that, I test it in a test app following [this example](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#ModalBottomSheet(kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.SheetState,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function0,androidx.compose.foundation.layout.WindowInsets,kotlin.Function1)).

The problem is that the `ModalBottomSheet` does not appear above the navigation bar. It's just overlapped:

[image]

I tried to add the `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` into the `AndroidManifest.xml` and

```
    WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, true) // -> no matter true or false. The same result.
```

into the `MainActivity.kt`. Also, I tried to play with `windowInsets` parameter of the `ModalBottomSheet` like

```
...,
windowInsets = WindowInsets.navigationBars
...,
```

But no results.

However, if the user uses `Gesture navigation` instead of `3-button navigation`, than it looks ok, which actually makes sense:

[image]

But I need to make it work correctly for `3-button navigation`, too.

How to achieve that?

Comment: IssueTracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/305565075

Comment: Try by adding .navigationBarsPadding() modifier to root layout or bottom sheet.

Comment: @GaneshHulyal I tried to add it to the root and and the bottom sheet, both did not work...